# Show that $\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\right)=0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

My question is:  Be $(\Omega,F,P)$  is a probability space and $A_1,A_2..∈F$

Show that if:
$$  \ P\left( A_n\right) = \frac{2^ne^{-2}}{n!}$$

So $\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\right)=0$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: $\Bbb P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) \le \Bbb P(A_n)$ for any $n$, so $\Bbb P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) \le \inf \{ \Bbb P(A_n) \mid n \}$, so it suffices to show that $\dfrac{2^ne^{-2}}{n!} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: rather a full answer than a hint...

Comment: @user859610 Not so full: the OP still has to show that limit...